# finding the change based on calculus

Tags: calculus

I am working on this calculus problem and i just cant seem to get the right answer can anyone help?

A winery owner has noticed that her wine receives $$P(x,y)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ points from a particular judge at a local wine competition if she invests $xx$ dollars for grapes per bottle and her winemaker's monthly salary is $y$ hundred dollars. Currently, she invests $\$6$ for grapes per bottle and her winemaker's monthly salary is $\$2,800$. Use calculus to estimate the increase in points from the judge when she decides to invest $\$8$ for grapes per bottle and increases her winemaker's monthly salary to $\$3,400$. Round your answer to the nearest tenth.

I found $\frac{dz}{dx}=(2\sqrt{y})/(3x^{1/3})$ and I found $\frac{dz}{dy}=(x^{2/3})/(2\sqrt{y})$ and then I multiplied $dz/dx\times 2$ which is the change in $x$ and then $dz/dy\times600$ which is the change in $y$ and i got the answer of 57.6 and thats wrong. I just cant seem to get this one right even though it worked for all the other problems of this type can anyone walk me through this problem?

Comment: The change in $y$ is $6$, not $600$, since $y$ is measured in hundreds of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

Using the derivatives of the function you are doing a linear approximation of the variation, i.e. you are approximating the function with a straight line, but, for the variations of $x$ and $y$ in the data this approximation gives a relevant error.

You can find a better result if you evaluate the  know function for the given values:

$$
P(6,2800)\approx 174.72 \qquad P(8,3400)\approx 233,24
$$
and find the difference.

Comment: that didnt work at all

Comment: Why  it does not work?